# Larger bounds for touch feedback of a View

Tags: android, android-view

I am looking for a solution to have larger bounds for selector of an Android view.

Imagine that View is a rectangle view. When user click on the view touch feedback that will be shown is a circle pretty larger than view bounds.

Do you know a good approach to build such an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to do that in view's bounds.(I think ). You can implement it by making visual action on parent background view.

```
            ImageButton im = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ur_btn);
            im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            float x = im.getX();
                            float y = im.getY();
                        }
                    });
        }
        private void addCircleBehindRectangle(int x, int y){
            RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(x, y);
            //optional margin l/r
            params.leftMargin = 50;
            params.topMargin = 60;
            parent.addView(iv, params);
        }
```

I hope it helps a little bit. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a view outside of its clipping area, you need to enable this in its parent container (any layout which derives from `ViewGroup`):

> [ViewGroup.clipChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren)

Another way is increase/decrease paddings of the clicked view itself.